# my rotation matrix for numpy (python) isn't working

Tags: python, numpy

i was making a program to display matrices under various transforms, and all of them work except for my rotation matrix. ive tried fiddling with it, but nothing seems to work

```
y = input("how many degrees do you want to rotate the shape around the origin?:    ")
j = array([(cos(int(y)), -sin(int(y))), (sin(int(y)), cos(int(y)))])
print(j.dot(w))
input("enter to exit")
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As the python documentation for [`cos`](http://docs.python.org/library/math.html#math.cos) and [`sin`](http://docs.python.org/library/math.html#math.sin) point out, the arguments should be in *radians*, not *degrees*.

You can use the [`math.radians`](http://docs.python.org/library/math.html#math.radians) function to convert degrees to radians.

Answer (score 2):

Your matrix is not correctly defined. Try

```
rotMatrix = array([[cos(angle), -sin(angle)], 
                   [sin(angle),  cos(angle)]])
```

If you define a vector, say

```
vector = array([1, 0])
```

you can then rotate this vector *around origin* using matrix multiplication method 'dot':

```
vector = rotMatrix.dot(vector)
```

The vector should be rotated around origin by `angle` degree (angle in radiant, as mentioned before).